# Error 10002 API PayPal Express Checkout PHP

Tags: php, api, paypal

Hello I ask for help because I can not communicate with the API PayPal (in PHP).
I encounter a synthetic error message (Error 10002).
I changed the identifiers several times, so it does not come from the.

Someone would have an idea, to help me because I am completely blocked.

[ScreenShot Return PayPal API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8Zdt.jpg)

```
$api_paypal = 'https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp?';
    $user = 'something';
    $pass = 'something';
    $signature = 'something';
    $params = array(
        'USER' => $user,
        'PWD' => $pass,
        'SIGNATURE' => $signature,
         'METHOD' => 'SetExpressCheckout',
        'VERSION' => 86,
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '40.00',
        'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'EUR',
        'cancelUrl' => 'http://www.google.fr',
        'returnUrl' => 'http://www.google.fr',
    );

    $params = http_build_query($params);
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $api_paypal,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $params,
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    dump($response);

    $responseArray = array();
    parse_str($response, $responseArray);

    curl_close($curl);
```